# C# EXT.NET: Hide window - delete contents

Tags: c#, extjs, ext.net

I have a window with `CloseAction=hide` but when I close it from codebehind:

```
WndwAddSVar.Close();
```

and reopen it the fields contain the previous values already. How I can make it to empty the values when I open it again?

Here is the window:

```
<ext:Window ID="WndwAddSVar" runat="server"

                    Width="650" Height="350" CloseAction="Hide"                      
                    X="120" Y="120" Hidden="true" Title="Add St Variables"
                    ConstrainHeader="true"
                    Layout="FitLayout">                                                
                    <Items>
                        <ext:FormPanel runat="server">
                            <Items>
                                <ext:FieldSet runat="server" Margin="5" Collapsible="false">
                                    <Items>
                                        <ext:TextField runat="server" ID="txtSName" FieldLabel="SName" />   
                                        <ext:NumberField runat="server" ID="numBlactor" FieldLabel="Blactor" />                                    
                                    </Items>
                                </ext:FieldSet>
                                <ext:ButtonGroup  runat="server">
                                    <Buttons>
                                        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Save">
                                            <DirectEvents>
                                                <Click OnEvent="Save" />
                                            </DirectEvents>
                                        </ext:Button>
                                        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Cancel">
                                            <Listeners>
                                                <Click Handler="#{WndwAddSVar}.close()" />
                                            </Listeners>
                                        </ext:Button>
                                    </Buttons>
                                </ext:ButtonGroup>
                            </Items>
                        </ext:FormPanel>
                    </Items>
                </ext:Window>
```

Comment: You could reset the form using the [reset method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-reset)

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs docs provide method to reset content of form component. You can refer [ExtJs docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-reset)

I have create small demo to show you, how it work. [Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26kg)

sample of code

```
var wind = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Testing',
    closeAction:'hide',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center',
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        border:0,
        bodyPadding:50,
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield'
        },
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Email'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Phone Number'
        }]
    }],
    listeners:{
        hide:function(){
            Ext.getCmp('openWind').show();
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text:'Open Window',
    id:'openWind',
    handler:function(){
        this.hide()
        wind.show().down('form').getForm().reset()
    }
})
```